# Rails wicked gem redirect with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using the wicked gem to build a form wizard. In the documentation, it is using the current_user object but I want to use a different object. I am struggling with adding a parameter to redirect_to so I can use this object.

**products_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @product = current_user.product.build(params[:product])
  @product.ip_address = request.remote_ip

  if @product.save
    redirect_to product_steps_path # This is where I think I need to pass product object but not sure how
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

**product_steps_controller.rb**

```
class ProductStepsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :apps, :templates

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    render_wizard
  end
end
```

**routes:**

```
resources :products
resources :product_steps
```

The error I get with the above code is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProductStepsController#show

Couldn't find Product with id=apps
```

How do I use the wicked gem on a specific object like this instead of the current_user example in the documentation?

Comment: can you post a solution on how you did it?

Answer (score 5):

This is what i got to work.

products_controller.rb

```
if @product.save
  redirect_to product_step_path(:id => "apps", : product_id => @ product.id)
else
...
```

product_steps_controller.rb

```
def show
  @asset = Asset.find(params[:asset_id])
  render_wizard
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The wizard gem takes `:id` parameter as step name. So you should not pass `:id` as the parameter since it will conflict with the step name.

**products_controller.rb**

```
redirect_to product_step_path(product_id: @product.id)
```

**product_steps_controller.rb**

```
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
```