# Rails 5 Multi-Step form using Wicked Gem is getting Forbidden Method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-gem

Been trying to figure out how to get a Multi Step form for an object a user will build using Wicked Wizard gem. I have been following the docs on the gem's github and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792258/rails-wicked-gem-understanding-routing/26808724#26808724) on that Scheem's answered himself, but I am getting a forbidden method error when on the last step of the wizard  and am trying to submit. I've seen in other questions, to refer to [strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), and I have been using that as well and am unsure what is causing the error. So far I have the following.

Error message:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):

app/controllers/places/steps_controller.rb:14:in `update'
Started GET "/places/20/steps/id" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-02 03:10:57 -0400
Processing by Places::StepsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"place_id"=>"20", "id"=>"id"}
  Place Load (183.0ms)  SELECT  "places".* FROM "places" WHERE "places"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering places/steps/id.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered places/steps/id.html.erb within layouts/application (851.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5753ms (Views: 4688.2ms | ActiveRecord: 183.0ms)


Started PUT "/places/20/steps/id" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-02 03:11:24 -0400
Processing by Places::StepsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/VrDWevWLY+A6841zIR5awBGopfnoXWxE8zf+6xkogJC6ufPQ+qYGp4Mg72N3Dlc547oSF/cXa4c/vMK+JU6qg==", "place"=>{"cost"=>"$100.00", "user_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Complete", "place_id"=>"20", "id"=>"id"}
  Place Load (14.9ms)  SELECT  "places".* FROM "places" WHERE "places"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (34.9ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 212ms (ActiveRecord: 49.8ms)



ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):

app/controllers/places/steps_controller.rb:14:in `update'
```

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170630190146) do

  create_table "places", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "location"
    t.string "cost"
    t.date "available"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "status"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_places_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.string "password_digest"
  end

end
```

place.rb

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

    validates :name, :location, :cost, :available, :presence => true, :if => :active?

  def active?
    status == 'active'      
  end

end
```

places_controller.rb

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_place, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /places
  # GET /places.json
  def index
    @places = Place.where.not(name: nil)
  end

  # GET /places/1
  # GET /places/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /places/new
  def new
    @place = Place.new
  end

  # GET /places/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /places
  # POST /places.json
  def create
    @place = Place.new
    if @place.save(validate: false)
      redirect_to place_step_path(place_id: @place.id, id: :date)
    else
      render new
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /places/1
  # PATCH/PUT /places/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @place.update(place_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @place }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /places/1
  # DELETE /places/1.json
  def destroy
    @place.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to places_url, notice: 'Place was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_place
      @place = Place.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def place_params
      params.require(:place).permit(:name, :location, :cost, :available, :user_id, :status)
    end
end
```

steps_controller.rb

```
class Places::StepsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

  steps :date, :id

  def show
    @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
    params[:place][:status] = 'active' if step == steps.last
    @place.update_attributes(params[:place])
    render_wizard @place
  end

  def create
    @place = Place.create
    redirect_to wizard_path(steps.first, :place_id => @product.id)

  end


private

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  resources :places
  resources :places do
    resources :steps, controller: 'places/steps'
  end


  resources :users



  # session routes
  resources :sessions
  get 'session/new'
  get '/sessions/new', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/sessions/new', to: 'sessions#create'
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

date.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @place, method: :put, url: wizard_path do |f| %>
  <% if f.object.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error-messages">
        <% f.object.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
          <p><%= error %></p>
          <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="h2">When Is Place available?</div>
  <div class="fied">
    <%= f.label "Date" %>
    <%= f.date_select :available, start_year: 2017 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Next" %>
    or <%= link_to "skip this step", next_wizard_path %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

id.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @place, method: :put, url: wizard_path do |f| %>
  <% if f.object.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error-messages">
      <% f.object.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
        <p><%= error %></p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="h2">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label "Cost" %>
      <%= f.text_field :cost %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label "Belongs to" %>
      <%= f.text_field :user_id %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Complete" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
>   (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError)

I believe the `update` method in `Places::StepsController` is the culprit. You are **not using** `strong params` in that method. Try changing it to below

```
def update
  @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
  params[:place][:status] = 'active' if step == steps.last
  @place.update_attributes(place_params) #here you should use strong params
  render_wizard @place
end
```

And define a `place_params` under the `private`

```
private
def place_params
  params.require(:place).permit(:name, :location, :cost, :available, :user_id, :status)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I appreciate the quick response, so I have stopped getting a forbiddenmethod error, and instead it is saying I "User must exist"  or if i skip the step it says the other fields can't be blank. Any Idea?

Comment: @LuisMejia If you are using Rails 5 Try setting `optional :true` in Place model `belongs_to :user, optional: true`

Comment: thanks again, that cleared up the User must exist, but the other fields are all saying "Cant Be Blank" and they are being filled, and listed in the params